# Posting recursive ajax call data on HTML(Angularjs)

Tags: html, angularjs, asynchronous

I am doing recursive ajax call and receiving server data. For each call, I receive some chunk of data. I want to show up that data on the front end. How do I do so that each received part of data is one below another. I hope this is clear.

for example

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Suppose I received first 10 lines on first ajax call, next 5 in next and so on, I want to show up as it is shown above, without wiping out first received data and showing 2nd received data. By the way I am using Angularjs for front end.

Added code snippet on Gaurav request.

```
callOnReq(requestId);
            function callOnReq(requestId) {
                    console.log('Request ID sent')
                    $http.post('/py/recvData',{'requestId':requestId}).
                        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log('Data after request ID')
                            $scope.recdData data.output;
                            if (data.output != ""){
                                callOnReq(requestId);
                            }else if (data.output == ""){
                                console.log('Data receiving over');
                            }
                        }).
                        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log(status);
                        });
                };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: post some code for what you have till now

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable in scope.

```
$scope.responseList=[];
```

Then push the response text in that

If response data  is list then you have to concate it

```
$scope.responseList=$scope.responseList.concat(data);
```

If response data single objecth then you have to push it

```
$scope.responseList.push(data);
```

Sample code

```
$http({
  // code
}).then(function(result){
   // data is list then you have to concate it 
   $scope.responseList=$scope.responseList.concat(data);
   // data is single objecth then you have to push it 
   $scope.responseList.push(data);
})
```

Then display `responseList` in the view.